# how does 'hostnamectl' command detect virtualization in Linux ARM64

Tags: virtual-machine

There are multiple command in linux like hostnamectl, systemd-detect-virt etc. that are able to detect virtualization in linux. However, **how are these command internally able to detect if the command is running on local machine or VM in linux ARM64?**

I m aware that in x64, there is a hypervisor bit set in the ECX register, but wanted to know if there is any similar flag set for the ARM64 architecture.

command:

> hostnamectl | grep 'Virtualization'

Output:

> Virtualization: amazon

There is no output printed if the command is run on a local machine.